# Error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Can anyone help?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidMidiDataException {

MusicEditorCreater.Builder builder = new MusicEditorCreater.Builder();

IMusicEditorModel model = MusicReader.parseFile(new FileReader(args[0]), builder);
IMusicEditorView view;
switch (args[1]) {
  case "text": view = new SheetMusicTextView();
    break;
  case "gui": view = new SheetMusicView();
    break;
  case "midi": view = new MidiView();
    break;
  case "combined": view = new MidiGuiView();
    break;
  default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid view");
}
```

I'm creating a Music Editor for class and this is the very last part, I just don't understand why it's throwing this error.
Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be calling this without passing in any args on the command line.

Comment: Some other similar questions may be found in [this Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+arrayindexoutofboundsexception+args+main).

Comment: Other than that you can put `switch (args[1]) {...` and  this `IMusicEditorModel model = MusicReader.parseFile(new FileReader(args[0]), builder);`  inside try-catch. Also you can do this inside `catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}`  This will tell you exactly what is going wrong in your code